# Scroll modal popup Elementor

Tags: elementor

How to make a modal window scroll in Elementor? As it is shown in the screenshots:

[image: Example #1 of a scrollable modal popup]

[image: Example #2 of a scrollable modal popup]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your customizer and on the custom css write:

```
.popup-container-class{
      overlay-y:scroll: !important;
}
```

Then inspect the scroll lines to find it's specific class in order to change respective color and sizes.